# WPF Binding Property not refreshing on update

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I've got a problem refreshing the binding to a property in my object. at initiating it shows fine result, but after i edit the source the value isn't refreshed in my window.

```
public class Marker : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<bool?> _repeat;
    [...]
    public ObservableCollection<bool?>    Repeat
    {
        get { return _repeat; }
        set 
        {
            _repeat = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Repeat"));
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("RepeatString"));
        }
    }

    [...]

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string RepeatString
    {
        get
        {
            string wt = string.Empty;
            wt += (bool)Repeat[0] ? "Mo, " : string.Empty;
            wt += (bool)Repeat[1] ? "Di, " : string.Empty;
            wt += (bool)Repeat[2] ? "Mi, " : string.Empty;
            wt += (bool)Repeat[3] ? "Do, " : string.Empty;
            wt += (bool)Repeat[4] ? "Fr, " : string.Empty;
            wt += (bool)Repeat[5] ? "Sa, " : string.Empty;
            wt += (bool)Repeat[6] ? "So, " : string.Empty;
            if (wt != string.Empty)
            {
                wt = wt.Remove(wt.Length - 2);
            }
            return wt;
        }
        [...]
    }
    [...]
}
```

In XAML part I've set bindings as following:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=lvMarker, Path=SelectedItem}">
    [...]
        <CheckBox Content="Montag" IsChecked="{Binding Repeat[0], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <CheckBox Content="Dienstag" IsChecked="{Binding Repeat[1], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <CheckBox Content="Mittwoch" IsChecked="{Binding Repeat[2], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <CheckBox Content="Donnerstag" IsChecked="{Binding Repeat[3], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <CheckBox Content="Freitag" IsChecked="{Binding Repeat[4], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <CheckBox Content="Samstag" IsChecked="{Binding Repeat[5], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <CheckBox Content="Sonntag" IsChecked="{Binding Repeat[6], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

this is updating the array just fine as I'm Clicking the Checkboxes. but not the following text block binding.

```
<ListView x:Name="lvMarker" ItemsSource="{Binding MarkerCollection}" Width="Auto" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource lvItemStyle}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            [...]
            <GridViewColumn Header="Zeit" Width="Auto" CellTemplate="{StaticResource DateCell}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

...

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DateCell">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock FontSize="14">
            [...]
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock FontSize="10" Text="{Binding RepeatString, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

What would I have to do to refresh the TextBlock representing RepeatString, when I change the bool? of Repeat[] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're raising `RepeatString` whenever the property of `Repeat` changes, but you want to subscribe to the changes of collection items.

Subscribe to collection changes of `Repeat` in your constructor (or wherever you instantiate `_repeat`).

```
public Marker()
{
    _repeat.CollectionChanged += Repeat_CollectionChanged;
}
```

Raise `PropertyChanged` of `RepeatString` upon collection changes.

```
private void Repeat_CollectionChanged(object sender, CollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("RepeatString"));
}
```